# How can I apply conditional formatting to a list of values returned by IMPORTRANGE() function based on if the value occurs in another column

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am using Google Sheets and have been able to import a range of values from another sheet into my desired sheet that I am working from. I want to highlight the values in the imported range based on whether they occur in a column of values present within my sheet. I've looked up multiple resources online, but have yet to find a solution. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: the importrange has nothing to do with it.  just try looking for help on "conditional formatting to highlight matches or not matches"

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your response. The import range was relevant to making my conditional formatting dynamic in regard to the range sheet values. It just took some more time to figure out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that runs into a similar issue, I found a solution. I applied a custom formula as a conditional formatting rule. Here is the formula I used. =NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$I:$I,1,FALSE))). For an in-depth explanation, consider this link: https://www.automateexcel.com/formulas/if-isna-vlookup-2/

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.